# How do you search database record with multiple words?

Tags: sql, ms-access

So, say i have a record in database like "Something with corn".

if i use sql like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%Something corn%'", the record wont show.

is there a way so when i search "Something Corn", i can get the record.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%Something%corn%';
```